# Configure debounce time in Windows for mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse

My mouse is broken and I am too lazy to buy a new one. The problem is with the left click button. A simple physical click will result in several clicks in Windows. There is already a debouncing circuit in the mouse to prevent this type of behavior, but it is no longer effective. How can I increase the debounce time in software? Or another to put it is how can I tell to Windows to ignore multiple mouse clicks if the time between them is less than 0.1 sec.

Comment: Just an idea: Windows has a built-in accessibility feature called Filter Keys that can debounce the keyboard. Maybe someone can hack it to work only on mouse buttons.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The free (and open source) tool [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) allows users to write custom scripts that interact with the keyboard and mouse. In particular, one user has written a script called "[Buggy Mouse](http://jslover.secsrv.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse.ahk)"([Fixed link to wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100301150549/http://jslover.secsrv.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse.ahk)) which "sets your mouse's minimum double-click speed (preventing single-clicks from being seen as double-clicks)". It does this by ignoring multiple clicks that occur too close to each other.

After installing AutoHotkey and loading the script, my own debouncing issues appear to have been solved.

You may need to adjust the `DoubleClick_Min` parameter at the top of the script which determines the minimum amount of time between mouse events to be considered as two independent clicks: I found that the default value caused legitimate double-clicks to be considered a bounce. The value of `75` seems to work well for me, however.

---

Edit 2021-02-18:
The Buggy Mouse link has rotted. However, [another user](https://superuser.com/a/1627162/348859) as posted a new link to what appears to be equivalent code although the `DoubleClick_Min` variable was renamed `DoubleClickMin_ms`. It is copied here in its entirety to prevent future rot.

```
/*
** Buggy-Mouse.ahk - Fix a buggy mouse. Stop it from double-clicking when you try to single-click.
**
**      NOTE: Please use this URL when linking to Buggy Mouse: r.secsrv.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse
**
**   Updated: Thu, Nov 1, 2012 --- 11/1/12, 10:19:19am EDT
**  Location: r.secsrv.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse
**
**  Keywords: mouse double clicks when I click once
**  Keywords: mouse double clicks when I single click
**  Keywords: mouse double clicks on its own
**  Keywords: mouse double clicks with one click
**  Keywords: mouse double clicks on single click
**  Keywords: mouse double clicks on one click
**  Keywords: mouse double-clicking when you single-click
**  Keywords: set mouse minimum double click speed
**  Keywords: debounce mouse
**
**    Author: JSLover - r.secsrv.net/JSLover - r.secsrv.net/JSLoverAHK
**
**      NOTE: Please use AutoHotkey 1.1+ (AutoHotkey_L) for this script!
**              AutoHotkey.com
**              L.AutoHotkey.net
**
**      NOTE: Compiled version available here: r.secsrv.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse.exe
**
*/
#SingleInstance force
OnExit, OnExit

;// **************************** Settings ****************************

;// Minimum double-click time. Any lower & it will be blocked (as being inhumanly fast).
DoubleClickMin_ms:=90

;// *** DISABLED *** ;// Minimum click after mouse-up time. Any lower & it will be blocked (as being inhumanly fast).
;// *** DISABLED *** ClickAfterMouseUpMin_ms:=100

;// **************************** /Settings ****************************

;// **************************** Advanded Settings ****************************

;// Enable logging if you need to report a bug.
;// Default (Disabled): Log=0
Log=0

;// Enable debugging if you want to see blocked/allowed clicks.
;// Default (Disabled): Debug=0
Debug=0

;// Enable this if you only want to see blocked clicks (when debugging is enabled).
;// Default (Enabled): Debug_OnlyBlocked=1
;// Note: Requires Debug (above) to be enabled (or no debugging will happen at all)
Debug_OnlyBlocked=1

;// **************************** /Advanded Settings ****************************

Gosub, OnStartup

;// *** Build Tray Menu ***

Text_ClicksBlocked=Clicks Blocked
Text_Debug=Debug
Text_Debug_OnlyBlocked=Debug (only blocked)

Menu, Tray, Add, %Text_ClicksBlocked%, BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_ClicksBlocked
    Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuCurrent:=Text_ClicksBlocked
    Menu, Tray, Default, %Text_ClicksBlocked%
Menu, Tray, Add, %Text_Debug%, BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_Debug
Menu, Tray, Add, %Text_Debug_OnlyBlocked%, BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_Debug_OnlyBlocked
    Menu, Tray, Disable, %Text_Debug_OnlyBlocked%

Menu, Tray, MainWindow
Menu, Tray, NoStandard
Menu, Tray, Add
Menu, Tray, Standard

;// *** /Build Tray Menu ***

;// BuggyMouse_Debug:=1
;// BuggyMouse_Debug_OnlyBlocked:=1
if (Debug) {
    Gosub, BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_Debug
}

if (Debug_OnlyBlocked) {
    Gosub, BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_Debug_OnlyBlocked
}
return

OnStartup:
logdir=%A_ScriptDir%
logfilename=%A_ScriptName%.log
logfile=%logdir%\%logfilename%

time:=time()
logmsg=
(LTrim
    %A_ScriptName%   Started`t`t%time%
    `  Status`t`tUpDn`t  Key`t`t`tReason`t`t`t`tWindow`n
)
log(logmsg)
return

OnExit:
time:=time()
logmsg=
(LTrim
    %A_ScriptName%    Exited`t`t%time%`n`n
)
log(logmsg)
ExitApp

*LButton::
*MButton::
*RButton::

A_ThisHotkey_VarSafe:=Hotkey_MakeVarSafe(A_ThisHotkey, "*")
A_ThisHotkey_NoModifiers:=Hotkey_RemoveModifiers(A_ThisHotkey)
;// A_ThisHotkey_Modifiers:=Hotkey_GetModifiers(A_ThisHotkey)
A_ThisHotkey_KeyName:=Hotkey_GetKeyName(A_ThisHotkey)

log_key:="Down`t" A_ThisHotkey "`t"
Critical
di++

TimeSinceLastMouseDown:=A_TickCount-LastMouseDown_ts

;// TimeSinceLastMouseUp:=A_TickCount-LastMouseUp_ts

DoubleClickTooFast:=TimeSinceLastMouseDown<=DoubleClickMin_ms

;// *** DISABLED *** ClickAfterMouseUpTooSoon:=(ClickAfterMouseUpMin_ms!="" && TimeSinceLastMouseUp<=ClickAfterMouseUpMin_ms)
;// if ((A_ThisHotkey==LastMouseDown && DoubleClickTooFast) || ClickAfterMouseUpTooSoon) {
if (A_ThisHotkey==LastMouseDown && (DoubleClickTooFast || ClickAfterMouseUpTooSoon)) {
;// if (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<=DoubleClickMin_ms) {
    reason:=DoubleClickTooFast ? "DoubleClickTooFast" "(" TimeSinceLastMouseDown ")" "(" DoubleClickMin_ms ")"
            : ClickAfterMouseUpTooSoon ? "ClickAfterMouseUpTooSoon" "(" TimeSinceLastMouseUp ")" "(" ClickAfterMouseUpMin_ms ")"
            : "Unknown"
    msg=`nblocked (%reason%)
    blockeddown:=1
    BlockedCount_Down++
    BlockedCount_%A_ThisHotkey_VarSafe%++
    Gosub, BuggyMouse_UpdateStatus_ClicksBlocked

    log_action:="BLOCKED`t"
} else {
    reason:=""
    Send, {Blind}{%A_ThisHotkey_KeyName% DownTemp}
    msg=`nSent, {Blind}{%A_ThisHotkey_KeyName% DownTemp}`n`n
    (LTrim C
        if (%A_ThisHotkey%==%LastMouseDown% && (%DoubleClickTooFast% || %ClickAfterMouseUpTooSoon%))
    )

    log_action:="`tallowed"
}
    BuggyMouse_DebugMsg_down=%di%: %A_ThisHotkey%(%TimeSinceLastMouseDown%)%LastMouseDown%%msg%
    msg=
    Gosub, BuggyMouse_Debug
LastMouseDown:=A_ThisHotkey
LastMouseDown_ts:=A_TickCount

wininfo:=WinGetInfo("a")
log(log_action "`t`t" log_key "`t`t" reason "`t`t`t`t`t" wininfo "`n")
return

*LButton up::
*MButton up::
*RButton up::

A_ThisHotkey_VarSafe:=Hotkey_MakeVarSafe(A_ThisHotkey, "*")
A_ThisHotkey_NoModifiers:=Hotkey_RemoveModifiers(A_ThisHotkey)
;// A_ThisHotkey_Modifiers:=Hotkey_GetModifiers(A_ThisHotkey)
A_ThisHotkey_KeyName:=Hotkey_GetKeyName(A_ThisHotkey)

log_key:=" Up `t" A_ThisHotkey
Critical
ui++
TimeSinceLastMouseUp:=A_TickCount-LastMouseUp_ts
;// if (A_ThisHotkey=A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<=DoubleClickMin_ms) {
;// if (A_ThisHotkey=LastMouseUp && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<=DoubleClickMin_ms) {
if (blockeddown) {
    msg=`nblocked
    blockedup:=1
    BlockedCount_Up++
    BlockedCount_%A_ThisHotkey_VarSafe%++
    Gosub, BuggyMouse_UpdateStatus_ClicksBlocked

    log_action:="BLOCKED`t"
} else {
    Send, {Blind}{%A_ThisHotkey_KeyName% up}
    msg=`nSent, {Blind}{%A_ThisHotkey_KeyName% up}
    log_action:="`tallowed"
}
;// if (BuggyMouse_Debug) {
    BuggyMouse_DebugMsg_up=%ui%: %A_ThisHotkey%(%TimeSinceLastMouseUp%)%LastMouseUp%%msg%
    msg=
    Gosub, BuggyMouse_Debug
;// }
blockeddown=
blockedup=
LastMouseUp:=A_ThisHotkey
LastMouseUp_ts:=A_TickCount

wininfo:=WinGetInfo("a")
log(log_action "`t`t" log_key "`t`t" reason "`t`t`t`t`t" wininfo "`n")
return

BuggyMouse_Debug_ShowLastMsg:
;// BuggyMouse_Debug_ShowLastMsg=1
BuggyMouse_Debug:
CoordMode, Tooltip
if (A_ThisLabel="BuggyMouse_Debug_ShowLastMsg"
        || (BuggyMouse_Debug && (!BuggyMouse_Debug_OnlyBlocked
            || (BuggyMouse_Debug_OnlyBlocked && (blockeddown||blockedup))))) {
    Tooltip, %BuggyMouse_DebugMsg_down%`n`n%BuggyMouse_DebugMsg_up%, 819, 619
} else {
    Tooltip
}
return

BuggyMouse_UpdateStatus_ClicksBlocked:
BlockedCount_Total:=BlockedCount_Down+BlockedCount_Up
Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuNew=%Text_ClicksBlocked%: %BlockedCount_Total%
Menu, Tray, Rename, %Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuCurrent%, %Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuNew%
Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuCurrent:=Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuNew
Menu, Tray, Tip, %Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuCurrent% - %A_ScriptName%
return

BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_ClicksBlocked:
msgbox, 64, ,
(LTrim C
    %Text_ClicksBlocked_MenuCurrent%

    Down(%BlockedCount_Down%)
    Up(%BlockedCount_Up%)

    LButton(%BlockedCount_LButton%)
    MButton(%BlockedCount_MButton%)
    RButton(%BlockedCount_RButton%)

    LButton up(%BlockedCount_LButton_up%)
    MButton up(%BlockedCount_MButton_up%)
    RButton up(%BlockedCount_RButton_up%)
)
return

BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_Debug:
BuggyMouse_Debug:=!BuggyMouse_Debug
Menu, Tray, ToggleCheck, %Text_Debug%
Menu, Tray, ToggleEnable, %Text_Debug_OnlyBlocked%
Tooltip
return

BuggyMouse_MenuSelect_Debug_OnlyBlocked:
BuggyMouse_Debug_OnlyBlocked:=!BuggyMouse_Debug_OnlyBlocked
Menu, Tray, ToggleCheck, %Text_Debug_OnlyBlocked%
Tooltip
return

Hotkey_MakeVarSafe(p_hotkey, p_ignorechars="") {
    replace:=p_hotkey

    StringReplace, replace, replace, $, % !InStr(p_ignorechars, "$") ? "KH_":""
    StringReplace, replace, replace, ~, % !InStr(p_ignorechars, "~") ? "PT_":""
    StringReplace, replace, replace, *, % !InStr(p_ignorechars, "*") ? "WC_":""

    StringReplace, replace, replace, <^>!, AltGr_
    StringReplace, replace, replace, <, L, a
    StringReplace, replace, replace, >, R, a
    StringReplace, replace, replace, &, and

    StringReplace, replace, replace, ^, Ctrl_, a
    StringReplace, replace, replace, +, Shift_, a
    StringReplace, replace, replace, #, Win_, a
    StringReplace, replace, replace, !, Alt_, a

    replace:=RegExReplace(replace, "i)[^a-z0-9_]", "_")

    p_hotkey:=replace

    return p_hotkey
}

Hotkey_GetModifiers(p_hotkey) {
    return RegExReplace(p_hotkey, "i)[\w\s]+$")
}

Hotkey_RemoveModifiers(p_hotkey) {
    return RegExReplace(p_hotkey, "i)^[^a-z0-9_]+")
}

Hotkey_GetKeyName(p_hotkey) {

    p_hotkey:=Hotkey_RemoveModifiers(p_hotkey)

    ;// Get string before 1st space...(removes "up" or "down" from name of key)
    Loop, Parse, p_hotkey, " "
    {
        p_hotkey:=A_LoopField
        break
    }

    return p_hotkey
}

log(p_msg, p_file="") {
    Global Log, logfile
    if (!Log) {
        return
    }
    if (p_file="") {
        p_file:=logfile
    }
    FileAppend, %p_msg%, %p_file%
}

time() {
    FormatTime, time, L1033, ddd, MMM d, yyyy --- M/d/yy h:mm:sstt
    return time
}

WinGetInfo(p_win, ByRef r_win_title="", ByRef r_win_class="") {
    WinGetTitle, win_title, %p_win%
    WinGetClass, win_class, %p_win%

    r_win_title:=(win_title ? win_title:"<no-title-info>")
    r_win_class:=(win_class ? win_class:"<no-class-info>")

    ;// wininfo:=(win_title ? win_title:"<no-title-info>") " - " (win_class ? win_class:"<no-class-info>")
    wininfo:=(win_class ? win_class:"<no-class-info>") ": " (win_title ? win_title:"<no-title-info>")
    return wininfo
}

;// #ScrollLock::log("*** PROBLEM ***`n")
^+#!F8::Gosub, BuggyMouse_Debug_ShowLastMsg
^+#!F9::Suspend
^+#!F12::ExitApp

/* ;// **************************** Changelog / Version History ****************************
**
**   Created: Fri, Apr 11, 2008 --- 4/11/08, 11:19:19am
**  Modified: Sat, Apr 12, 2008 --- 4/12/08, 5:38:19am
**  Modified: Sun, Jul 10, 2011 --- 7/10/11, 3:19:19am EDT
**      * Added blocking of "mouse down too soon after last mouse up"
**  Modified: Wed, Jul 20, 2011 --- 7/20/11, 1:19:19pm EDT
**  Modified: Thu, Aug 25, 2011 --- 8/25/11, 1:19:19am EDT
**      * Temporarily disabled "mouse down too soon after last mouse up" blocking, until I get it working.
**  Modified: Thu, Aug 25, 2011 --- 8/25/11, 2:38:19am EDT
**      * Updated Keywords for search engines
**  Modified: Sat, Aug 27, 2011 --- 8/27/11, 7:19:19am EDT
**      * Added Logging
**  Modified: Sat, Aug 27, 2011 --- 8/27/11, 2:38:19pm EDT
**      * Added Window Info to log
**  Modified: Sun, May 13, 2012 --- 5/13/12, 7:19:19pm EDT
**      * Added support for blocking mouse clicks while holding down keyboard keys
**  Modified: Mon, May 14, 2012 --- 5/14/12, 10:19:19am EDT
**      * Updated Hotkey_MakeVarSafe()
**  Modified: Tue, May 15, 2012 --- 5/15/12, 7:19:19am EDT
**      * Hotkey_MakeVarSafe(): Fixed error msg/incompatibility with AutoHotkey < 1.1
**  Modified: Thu, Nov 1, 2012 --- 11/1/12, 10:19:19am EDT
**      * Made Debugging default to Off
**      * Added "Debug" & "Debug_OnlyBlocked" to Settings section, for easier toggling of the default state
**
*/ ;// **************************** /Changelog / Version History ****************************
```

Comment: That's a wonderful script! Unfortunately it doesn't handle dragging well when the mouse bounces. The mouse button will register as not being held.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I can't post comments, but I wanted to add to daviddg's answer.  Searching the scripts section of the AutoHotkey web site did not find anything for "Buggy Mouse".  However, I did find a script on this post:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/82509-software-fix-for-double-clicking-mouse

And the script source is:

```
LButton::
If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 100) ;hyperclick
Return
sendinput {LButton down}
KeyWait, LButton
sendinput {LButton up}
Return
```