# Is there some way to limit the fastest mouse click input speed?

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

I'm having some issues with my mouse, a Roccat Tyon, in that it seems to be erroneously sending two rapid click inputs on a single click, for both left and right mouse buttons.

I've updated my drivers but that doesn't seem to have helped - I suspect it's a physical issue (though a weird one).

So I'm wondering if there's any method to effectively say "If I click twice within [x] milliseconds, disregard the second click". I've thought of maybe trying to use something like AutoHotkey but I'm not sure how I'd set it up to do this. Otherwise some kind of system-wide mouse hook or something but again I'm not aware of anything I could use for that.

Any ideas?

Comment: May i suggest that you  check your hardware for glitchy wiring or connectors, alternatively your mouse has broken electronics in it; the switches for the buttons may be broken - but both at the same times seems as a bit weird coincidence.

Comment: This is a common failure in the microswitch within the mouse. I've had mice last for years and some fail within months and there isn't anything you can do except replace it.

Comment: Strange with BOTH broken at the same time though... but maybe not "impossible".

Comment: One of the duplicates (https://superuser.com/questions/207731/configure-debounce-time-in-windows-for-mouse) has a potential software fix but I've not tried it.

Comment: @Hannu: not that strange... it's called wear, it just takes time.

Comment: Well, you'd be using BOTH buttons just as much, ;-) - well maybe if playing games.